# R.drawable cannot resolve image

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have checked a lot of questions on stackoverflow and I seem to have all the correct things but my R.drawable wont detect my image. It is in /res/drawable and in all the other folders (mdpi, hdpi etc.)

```
ShipImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.player);
```

And here is my R.java

```
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int background=0x7f020000;
        public static final int buttons=0x7f020001;
        public static final int dead=0x7f020002;
        public static final int enemy=0x7f020003;
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020004;
        public static final int play_btn=0x7f020005;
        public static final int player=0x7f020006;
    }
```

Comment: Does it show up as a "could not be resolved error?" What error do you see?

Comment: you have try after cleaning project from Project->Clean.. option on Eclipse IDE

Comment: Tried Clean, didn't help. The error I get is "player cannot be resolved or is not a field". tried renaming too. didn't work

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Are you sure You import `import com.yourcompanyname.product.R` ?

**instead of**

`import android.R;`

Comment: Well I had         import com.fasih.bounce.R.drawable;
but this worked. thanks

Comment: Thanks to this response, I was able to see that my Manifest `package` setting pointed to a previous name of the project's package, meaning it was resolving the wrong R for the project.

Answer (score 2):

`import com.yourcompanyname.product.R` differs from `import android.R`

First is your project R file, that is generated by SDK.

`import android.R` is built-in R file, that is provided by Android.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your image is png.
Also check that you have saved the layout where you have to inflate the image.

Answer (score 0):

Check the package of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your module and make sure that it has been defined correctly.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.mobius.featureWelcome">
</manifest>
```

Finally use the package as an import in the class:

```
import app.mobius.featureWelcome.R
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you import import android.R; delete this line and import again.

```
import android.R;
```